# Haskell Warning: Pattern match is redundant

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have created a function in Haskell to counts the number of functions and operators in the given expression.

```
size :: Expr -> Int
size (Num n) = 1
size x       = 1
size (Function f e) = 1 + size e
size (Operation o e1 e2) = 1 + size e1 + size e2
```

Though it's working as expected without any errors, I am getting a warning: [-Woverlapping-patterns] saying  Pattern match is redundant. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Everything after the `x` will never "fire", since `x` will capture *any* value.

Comment: "Though it's working as expected". Are you sure about that? Try to find a value for `e` such that `size e` returns anything except 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of `case` clause matters – the incoming value is matched to patterns from top to bottom and if any of these checks succeeds, that option is taken. In your case a variable `x` will successfully match to *anything* by assigning `x` to that thing. Therefore, all cases below it won't ever be considered.

Perhaps you wanted:

```
size :: Expr -> Int
size (Num n) = 1  -- btw, you can skip this line
size (Function f e) = 1 + size e
size (Operation o e1 e2) = 1 + size e1 + size e2
size x       = 1
```